# Flagging duplicates in Excel based on Date and Email address

Tags: excel

I am needing a way to look at a list of survey responses in an Excel document and remove duplicates following this rule: Up to three responses are allowed per day, per email address.

I have a spreadsheet that has the date in the first column and the email address in the second column.

I need to change the formatting on any rows that have **more than** three duplicate email addresses on the same date.

Thanks in advance for the help

**Edit:** I'd prefer to do this inside the Excel document, but could also tackle it in C# or PHP if there is not a solution for this in Excel

Comment: Are you using any particular programming language for this?

Comment: I'd prefer to do this inside the Excel document, but could also tackle it in C# or PHP if there is not a solution for this in Excel

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are wanting is fairly simple, try this:

[image]

Then you can easily identify the offending posts by adding conditional formatting:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not getting the initial formula in D2 to work correctly. Can you provide a little more detail into how that formula would look on subsequent lines?

Comment: The formula in cell D3 would be =countifs($B$2:$B3,B3,$C$2:$C3,C3). The formula in cell D4 would be =countifs($B$2:$B4,B4,$C$2:$C4,C4)

Comment: If you need additional help, I suggest looking up "Excel Countifs formula" on a search engine. Here's the official Microsoft link:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx